# reading from a text file that contains numbers and characters

Tags: c++

I recently learned how to read data from a text file, but I would like to continue expanding my knowledge on that matter. I would like to read files that contain numbers and characters. Can anyone give me some advice please?

The following is the code I wrote to read numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile("input.txt", ios::in);

    if (!infile) {
        cout << "Inputxxxxx file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ofstream outfile ("outputt.txt", ios::out);
    if (!outfile) {
        cout << "inputssss file could not be opened " <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int number;
    int answer[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
        infile >> number;
        answer[i]=number;

        cout << answer[i] << " ";
        outfile <<answer[i]<< " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to know how you can read a file that has text and numbers in it? so you can output it to another file and the console?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file parse" and you should find something similar to your question, already answered.